# Integrating our custom automation framework with CI server (Bamboo)

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, bamboo

We are having our own Test Automation tool written in Java which takes Json Scripts as input.
Now what i want is to integrate our Test Automation tool with bamboo so that after every build the Test Automation tool should be triggered to run all the Json Scripts.
Is it possible really??
As per my understanding i need to develop a plugin that can do this work.Am i moving in the right direction?

Thanks in Advance